# How to best display a legal statement in a responsive menu?

Tags: menu, information, legal, responsive

If you have a responsive menu for "accounts" so you can switch between accounts. But then want to display a block of information (for legal reasons) how do you think the best way to do this would be? I don't want to confuse the user, nor want them to not think the legal information is about the account and not the add another account.

Below is a prototype of how it currently is, and how it could potentially be.

[image: user accounts]

Can you even have blocks of information in responsive tabs/menus?

Comment: I'm a little confused by your question--is the legal information about the new account specifically or all of the accounts generally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, you want to put a legal notice that only relates to the "add account" action. A simple fix would be to add more visual separation with a line or different background colors for these two related but different sections.

[image]